# What made Seleucid monarchy so unstable?

Tags: ancient-history, political-history, monarchy, civil-war

I would not claim that the Seleucid monarchy was more unstable than other Hellenistic monarchies (though contemporary Antigonid Macedonia appears to be more politically robust) but throughout the 3rd century BC family feuds and other forms of inner political strife for supreme power seem to be a recurrent thread that only intensifies in the 2nd century onwards.

Were there any institutional features of the Hellenistic monarchy of the Seleucid dynasty which made it so prone to inner political turbulence? What made a potential provincial usurpers or king's relatives so confident in attempting to seize political power?

Perhaps neighbouring states could deliberately contribute to the inner intrigues in the Seleucid court or take advantage of existing strife (like Maccabeans did) but I assume that it is merely an exacerbating factor, not the very cause of the turbulence.

Comment: Was it even especially unstable compared with similar regional states? The Parthian state seems to have been less than stable and Byzantium's political strife is legendary.

Comment: the Seleucid reign really only had a strong power base for about 100 years and then nearly incessant warfare, really stupid military campaigns, and picking fights with Rome for really minimal gains, sort of did them in.  then the monarchy turned and devoured itself with petty infighting and other really dumb wars against their neighbors.

Comment: @ed.hank no argument against that but if we consider inept foreign policy as a reason for the lack of inner stability, there must be a reason for the monarchy of being so indiscriminate in choosing an appropriate military opponent